# mypy argument after ** must be a mapping

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy

There is a piece of code that builds question objects in loop and for each question optionally builds possibleAnswers object.

Class for Question is:

```
class Question(graphene.ObjectType):  # type: ignore
    qId = graphene.String()
    label = graphene.String()
    question = graphene.String()
    multipleAnswersAccepted = graphene.Boolean()
    possibleAnswers = graphene.List(PossibleAnswer)

def __init__(self, questionObj: QuestionMeta) -> None:
    print("__ questionObj type={y}".format(y=type(questionObj)))

    self.qId = questionObj.qPointer
    self.label = questionObj.label
    self.question = questionObj.question
    self.inputType = questionObj.inputType
    self.multipleAnswersAccepted = questionObj.multipleAnswersAccepted
    if questionObj.possibleAnswersPointer:
        self.possibleAnswers = []
        for _key, value in enumerate(questionObj.possibleAnswersPointer):
            print("___possibleAnswersPointer is {}".format(
                type(value)))
            # x = PossibleAnswerMeta(**value)
            possibleAnswer = PossibleAnswer(paObj=PossibleAnswerMeta(**value))
            self.addPossibleAnswer(possibleAnswer)
    else:
        self.possibleAnswers = None

def addPossibleAnswer(self, possibleAnswer: Dict[int, str]) -> None:
    """Append possible-answer object to array of possible answers."""
    self.possibleAnswers.append(possibleAnswer)
```

Class for possibleAnswer is

```
class PossibleAnswer(graphene.ObjectType):  # type: ignore
    paId = graphene.String()
    text = graphene.String()

    def __init__(self, paObj: PossibleAnswerMeta) -> None:
        print("__ paObj type={y}".format(y=type(paObj)))
        self.paId = paObj.paId
        self.text = paObj.text
```

and both classes in creators use objects of type defined as `QuestionMeta` or `PossibleAnswerMeta`, which are defined in `classes` module:

```
class PossibleAnswerMeta(NamedTuple):
    text: str
    paId: int
    score: int


class QuestionMeta(NamedTuple):
    qPointer: str
    label: str
    question: str
    multipleAnswersAccepted: bool
    possibleAnswersPointer: List[PossibleAnswerMeta]
```

And the piece of loop that creates questions is:

```
for _questionNum, questionData in enumerate(value):
    print("___questionData type is {}".format(type(questionData)))
    q = Question(questionObj=QuestionMeta(**questionData))
    s.addQuestion(question=q)
```

So we can see that Question gets `questionObj=QuestionMeta(**questionData)` as argument, and possibleAnswer is getting `paObj=PossibleAnswerMeta(**value)`.

Both are NamedTuple based types, both `questionData` and `value` have the same type `<class 'dict'>`, but mypy complains only about value.

When I run mypy I get the following output:

`..79: error: Argument after ** must be a mapping`, where line 79 is line `possibleAnswer = PossibleAnswer(paObj=PossibleAnswerMeta(**value))`.

**Question:**
Code runs OK correct,
both objects are created properly (I see them returned in graphene query), the types of arguments are the same, which is printed in the log

So why mypy is complaining only about passing value, not about questionData as both are types od 'dict'?

```
 ...
 __ questionObj type=<class 'user.api.meta.classes.QuestionMeta'>
 ___possibleAnswersPointer is <class 'dict'>
 __ paObj type=<class 'user.api.meta.classes.PossibleAnswerMeta'>
 ___possibleAnswersPointer is <class 'dict'>
 __ paObj type=<class 'user.api.meta.classes.PossibleAnswerMeta'>
 ___possibleAnswersPointer is <class 'dict'>
 __ paObj type=<class 'user.api.meta.classes.PossibleAnswerMeta'>
 ___questionData type is <class 'dict'>
 __ questionObj type=<class 'user.api.meta.classes.QuestionMeta'>
 ___possibleAnswersPointer is <class 'dict'>
 __ paObj type=<class 'user.api.meta.classes.PossibleAnswerMeta'>
 ___possibleAnswersPointer is <class 'dict'>
 __ paObj type=<class 'user.api.meta.classes.PossibleAnswerMeta'>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a real problem with your types that mypy is correctly warning you about.

Let's look at all those lines in the output that say

```
___possibleAnswersPointer is <class 'dict'>
```

First, that's not `possibleAnswersPointer`. You're printing a misleading message; this is the class of an element of `possibleAnswersPointer`.

Second, the elements of `possibleAnswersPointer` **should not be dicts**. You told mypy that they'd be something else entirely:

```
possibleAnswersPointer: List[PossibleAnswerMeta]
```

You told mypy that the elements of `possibleAnswersPointer` would be instances of `PossibleAnswerMeta`. mypy is absolutely correct to warn you that instances of `PossibleAnswerMeta` are not mappings and cannot be unpacked with `**`. You don't get a runtime error because the elements of `possibleAnswersPointer` aren't what you told mypy they would be.

---

If the elements of `possibleAnswersPointer` aren't supposed to be instances of `PossibleAnswerMeta`, then don't tell mypy that they will be instances of that class. If the elements of `possibleAnswersPointer` *are* supposed to be instances of `PossibleAnswerMeta`, then you have the bug mypy warned you about, as well as whatever bug caused those elements to be dicts.

Comment: Thank You! That clears a lot, I have to spam You with few more questions. a) Isn't the situation for Question exactly the same (mypy says 'no', as no error here)? I am looking at the code and can not spot the difference. b) You are touching the root of the problem: I am unfamiliar with object types, casting and proper usage: how can I access what I expect to find inside object that `enumerate` returns?